# How to prevent auto form submission inside for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, ajaxform

I want to take some information trough a form in each loop count. Where I have ajax to save those information and then ask again for the informations in the next loop count. But, unfortunately it doesn't work, it saves the same information for each count. So I want to prevent this auto submission of form after submitting once. So please help me in this, Thanks in advance!

```
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxArr.length; i++) {

            var quoteModal = document.getElementById('quoteModal');
                quoteModal.style.display = "block";
                getContextId = checkboxArr[i];

            $('#quote_pn').on('submit', function(e){

                e.preventDefault();

                var addTotalQuote = parseFloat($('.shipping').val()) / checkboxArr.length;

                $.ajax({
                    type        : "POST",
                    data        : {getContextId: getContextId},
                    url         : "<?php echo site_url(); ?>" + "/partnumber/read_table",
                    dataType    : "json",
                    success     : function(data) {
                        var margin = parseFloat($('.margin').val());
                        var shipping = parseFloat($('.shipping').val());

                        var percantage = margin / 100;

                        var ind_cost = parseFloat(data.unit_price);
                        var qty = parseInt($('#quote_pn .quantity').val());

                        var unit_sell_price = percantage * ind_cost;
                        var total_unit_price = unit_sell_price + ind_cost;

                        var grand_sell_total = total_unit_price * qty;

                        var ind_landedCost = grand_sell_total / qty;

                        addTotalQuote = addTotalQuote + grand_sell_total;

                        var customer = $('#quote_pn .customer').val(),
                            manufac = data.manufac,
                            part = data.part,
                            step_code = data.step_code,
                            date_code = data.date_code,
                            warranty = data.warranty,
                            desc = data.description,
                            fob = data.fob,
                            stock = data.stock,
                            condition = data.condit,
                            unit_price = ind_landedCost,
                            quantity = qty,
                            target = data.target,
                            indcost = ind_cost,
                            ship = shipping;

                            $.ajax({
                                type    : "POST",
                                data    : { customer: customer, manufac:manufac, part: part, step_code: step_code, date_code: date_code, warranty: warranty, desc: desc, fob: fob, stock: stock, condition: condition, unit_price: unit_price, qty: quantity, target: target, ind_cost: indcost, shipping: ship},
                                url     : "<?php echo site_url(); ?>" + "/partnumber/insert_new_quote",
                                success : function(XHR, status, response) {
                                    alert("Quote has been added!");
                                    quoteModal.style.display = "none";
                                    $('#quote_pn')[0].reset();
                                },
                                error: function (XHR, status, response) {
                                   alert(response);
                                }

                            });
                    },
                    error       : function (XHR, status, response) {
                       alert(response);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` as well to the code.

`e.preventDefault();` + `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` will stop automatic sumbission.

the alternative is to use `return false;`

Comment: Doesn't work for me. `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` stops loop immediately.